# Iterating through facebook comments JSON object failing

Tags: json, facebook-comments

I tried the option of students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data.length. However, the item["http://www.myurl.com"] call is not working.

If I take out the URL from JSON object and write the iterator with students.comments.data, it works.

Here is my code, any help highly appreciated.

```
var students = {
    "http://www.myurl.com":{
        "comments":{
                "data" : [{
                    "id": "123456778",
                    "from": {
                        "name": "XYZ",
                        "id": "1000005"
                        },
                    "message": "Hey",
                    "can_remove": false,
                    "created_time": "2012-09-03T03:16:01+0000",
                    "like_count": 0,
                    "user_likes": false
                }] 
            }
        }
    }

var i=0
var arrayObject = new Array();
alert("Parsing 2:   "+students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data.length);
for(i=0;i<students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data.length;i++)
{
    alert("Parsing 1:  "+i);
    arrayObject.push(students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data[i].id);
    arrayObject.push(students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data[i].message);
    arrayObject.push(students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data[i].created_time);
}
```

Comment: Where is the .item coming from?  This seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `students` object has no `item` property only `http://www.myurl.com`. Use `students["http://www.myurl.com"]` not `students.item["http://www.myurl.com"]`